# Vue data variable not updating after language change

Tags: vue.js

I have a data variable as follows:

```
data(){
  return {
    amount: {
      active: false,
      name: this.$i18n.t('key_name'),
      value: this.$i18n.t('key_value')
    }
  }
}
```

The data variable is using localized string. The issue is that, when I change the language from a dropdown, the `amount` variable is not updating until any other event occurs. I believe this has something to do with the `$nextTick()`.

But not sure how to handle this properly as to have the changes reflected immediately in the `amount` variable.

I can't make it as a computed property as I've to assign values to this variable at a later point.

like this:

```
this.amount.active = true
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell how you use Vue i18n, but you can use a [watcher](http://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/guide/sfc.html#basic-usage) as it is stated in the docs and watch for the global [i18n.locale object](http://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/guide/locale.html), something like:

```
<script>
export default {
  name: 'app',
  data () {
    return {
      amount: {
        active: false,
        name: this.$i18n.t('key_name'),
        value: this.$i18n.t('key_value')
      }
    }
  },
  watch: {
    this.$i18n.locale (val) {
      this.amount.active = true
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Depends how it's configured in your project.